# Jquery Alertify in DevExpress Gridview ClientSidEevents

Tags: c#, jquery, gridview, devexpress, alertify

I try to use a jquery alert plugin 'alertify' to replace the 'confirm delete' ability in DevExpress GridView. Below is my code, it won't go to **ASPxGridView2_CustomButtonCallback**. Can someone help to advice?

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="sql_source" KeyFieldName="UID"
Width="100%" 
OnCustomButtonCallback="ASPxGridView2_CustomButtonCallback">

<ClientSideEvents CustomButtonClick="function(s, e) {
     alertify.confirm('are you sure?', function (c) {
        if (c) {
            alertify.log('Deleted!');
            e.processOnServer = true;
        } else {
            alertify.log('Cancel!');
        }
     });}
"/>

<Columns>
  <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0" Width="120px" ShowInCustomizationForm="True">
      <EditButton Visible="True"></EditButton>
      <CustomButtons>
          <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="CustDel" Text="MyDel">
          </dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
      </CustomButtons>
      <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></CellStyle>
   </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
</Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the property EnableCallBacks to "True" for your GridView

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="sql_source" KeyFieldName="UID" Width="100%"
    EnableCallBacks="True" OnCustomButtonCallback="ASPxGridView2_CustomButtonCallback">
```

Comment: not work! However, I solve my problem by below steps. Add a javascript function to use ajax method to delete record in code-behind. Then 'call this javascript function' to replace 'e.processOnServer = true'.